# Collection of array objects being pushed into existing array in the same index

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image]

```
ipRecords: any;

 this.auth.fileUpload(fd).subscribe((res: any)=>{
        if(res.status==="Success"){
          this.toastr.success("File Uploaded");
          this.ipRecords.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data)));
});
```

in the iprecords array when i push the new data it gets pushed in the same index 10. I want that items inside it should be pushed. this.ipRecords = res.data works fine but it overwrites the existing items

Comment: Try [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array using `...` like this: `this.ipRecords.push(...JSON.parse`

Comment: Can you provide sample Array in the form of Code?

Answer (score 0):

That's it:) use Array.prototype.concat or spread operator.
And why are you using so tricky stuff (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify))?

```
 this.auth.fileUpload(fd).subscribe((res: any)=>{
        if(res.status==="Success"){
          this.toastr.success("File Uploaded");
          this.ipRecords.push(...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data)));
});
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` is probably for cloning `res.data`

Comment: yes, but why?)) this res might be come from observable

Comment: yes i m using it because of an issue there is another array which needs to keep a copy of this if i dont use it then both array gets 2 copies  if the same pushed data as opposed to one